# How to make CSS height 100% scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I want to make the two-tone background. 50% of left side is in the main background color and 50% right side in another color (say pink). I could accomplish that but now facing another problem. When the mouse cursor is on the pink background color, the page becomes unscrollable. How to fix this and make it scrollable?

html code

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing is scrollable here with your current code, no matter where cursor is, only the scrolls are visible

Comment: Remove ``overflow: scroll`` and it should scroll with mouse inside pink area.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this by changing height: 100% in html, body to

```
min-height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont't have to use another div for two-tone background you can acheive by just this:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, pink 0%,pink 50%,#000000 50%,white 50%,white 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Have a look at a working pen [here](https://codepen.io/nipun-jain-the-decoder/pen/LYVZywG)
If you want to follow the approach you are doing then yes you can give `min-height: 100%;` to html.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not using `background gradient`  with single div without
>   positioning like below

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f5f5f5 50% , pink 50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background"></div>
</body>
```